# Registration with profile picture using services in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-services

I've been trying to upload a user profile picture during the user registration using Service 3 and so far I haven't had any luck. I tested passing a hard coded fid in the field "picture" and also tried to pass the fields "filemime", "filename", etc. and it didn't work neither.
Any idea about what fields I need to populate?

I guess it must be related to this post [Using Drupal Services and DIOS SDK for setting user picture in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986966/using-drupal-services-and-dios-sdk-for-setting-user-picture-in-ios-app)
but it doesn't have and answer neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use following code -

```
//Picture is first uploaded from ios using file service and fid is passed in $data object
$file_contents_object = file_load($data->picture_fid);
$file_contents_array['fid'] = $file_contents_object->fid;
$file_contents_array['uid'] = $file_contents_object->uid;
$file_contents_array['filename'] = $file_contents_object->filename;
$file_contents_array['uri'] = $file_contents_object->uri;
$file_contents_array['filemime'] = $file_contents_object->filemime;
$file_contents_array['filesize'] = $file_contents_object->filesize;
$file_contents_array['status'] = $file_contents_object->status;
$file_contents_array['timestamp'] = $file_contents_object->timestamp;
$file_contents_array['rdf_mapping'] = $file_contents_object->rdf_mapping;
//use your cck field here
$user_obj->field_user_profile_picture['und'][0] = $file_contents_array;
```

Hope this will help.